# ICMP packet with correct mac address but wrong ip address

Tags: ip, mac-address, ip-address, icmp, mac

I was wondering what would happen if you send an ICMP request with the correct mac address but the wrong ip on a local network. Would the request reach the computer with the correct mac address since the switch only cares about the mac address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is as you said. The computer with that MAC address will receive the ethernet frame, since on layer 2 it's all good. Then, looking at layer 3, it will discard the IP packet, since the IP address is incorrect.